# While reuse cell and set UISwitch active or not, ios listview set active the first row and last, what is wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

My Code above should fill the ios list with my model symptom:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell {
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SymptomTableCell", bundle: nil),
                              forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
            as? SymptomTableCell {
            print(indexPath.row)
            print(cell)
            let symptom = symptoms[indexPath.row]
            if Editor.isEditing {
                cell.setDatasource(symptom, isSelected:
                    hasSymptom(symptomsEdit, oid: symptom.oid))
            } else {
               cell.setDatasource(symptom, isSelected: cell.swItem.on)
            }
            cell.tag = Helper.random()
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            tableCells.append(cell)
            return cell
        }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

[first cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTsZe.png)

[last cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yR1p.png)

These two are my objects to fulfill the UITableView You can see the images attached to understand the error:

```
import Foundation
import EVReflection

class Symptom: EVObject {
    var oid = ""
    var name = ""
}


import UIKit

class SymptomTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    var symptom: Symptom?
    @IBOutlet weak var swItem: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblItem: UILabel!

    func setDatasource(symptom: Symptom, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.symptom = symptom
        lblItem.text = symptom.name
        swItem.on = isSelected
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Do not call `registerNib` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Do it once in `viewDidLoad`. 2) Don't use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. It can't return a `nil` cell.

Comment: Probably it is because you call registerNib inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. First, as rmaddy mentioned in comment, remove:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SymptomTableCell", bundle: nil),
                          forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, that needs to go in `viewDidLoad()`.

Secondly, within your custom cell class I would override `prepareForReuse` and set the switches to off state and then turn them on as needed in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your VC like your currently are:

```
class SymptomTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    var symptom: Symptom?
    @IBOutlet weak var swItem: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblItem: UILabel!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
         self.swItem.setOn(false, animated: false)
    }

    func setDatasource(symptom: Symptom, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.symptom = symptom
        lblItem.text = symptom.name
        swItem.on = isSelected
    }

}
```